# how can i make a dropdown in this sidebar when clicking?

Tags: reactjs

*I'm stuck right now on how I can make a drop-down menu in the sidebar, so when I click on it I should show or hide a submenu*

[Text](https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-frog-7nm1n)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to add a class to hide and show elements

**sidebar.js**

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import "./style.css";

class sidebar extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isOpen: false,
  };

  toggleClass = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState((prevState) => ({isOpen: !prevState.isOpen}));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div class="sidenav ">
        <a href="/">Retour a l'acceuil</a>
        <a href="/" onClick={this.toggleClass}>
          <span
            class="iconify hamburger"
            data-inline="false"
            data-icon="ic:round-menu"
          />
          Liste des élèves
          <span
            class="iconify down"
            data-inline="false"
            data-icon="bx:bxs-down-arrow"
          />
          </a>
        <div className={this.state.isOpen ? 'show': 'hide'} >
        <a href="/">
          <span
            class="iconify"
            data-inline="false"
            data-icon="ic:baseline-keyboard-arrow-right"
          />
          Item1
        </a>
        <a href="/">
          <span
            class="iconify"
            data-inline="false"
            data-icon="ic:baseline-keyboard-arrow-right"
          />
          Item2
        </a>
        <a href="/">
          <span
            class="iconify"
            data-inline="false"
            data-icon="ic:baseline-keyboard-arrow-right"
          />
          Item3
        </a>
        </div>

        <a href="/">Abscences</a>
        <a href="/">Inscription au concours</a>
        <a href="/">Résultat</a>
        <a href="/">Messagerie</a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default sidebar;
```

**style.css**

```
...
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```